# Read a file line by line for integers

Tags: c

I just want to output 3 integers from the file. Why this doesn't work? I get -1079184140 and similar.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

   FILE* stream  = fopen(argv[2], "r");

   char line[80];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    fgets(line, 80, stream);
    printf("%d \n", line);
  } 

  fclose(streamForInput);

}
```

Comment: You tell `printf` you're passing in an `int` and then you stab it in the back and pass a `char[]`.

Comment: Your code has UB, and basically no chance of working for any reasonable definition of "working". Perhaps if you show us the input format, and a reasonable description of what you're trying to accomplish, we could help you.

Comment: @hey, the character limit is there for a reason. If you are adding more information to your question you should edit your question, not add a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/).

```
int number;
sscanf (line, "%d", &number);
printf ("%d \n", number);
```

That will pull the first integer on a line. This is not the most secure or robust way, but that is out of scope.

PS:

```
fclose(streamForInput);
```

Should be:

```
fclose(stream);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. The first problem is:

```
   printf("%d \n", line);
```

because line is a char[]. But you use a %d to output it, so you output line, which is an address. So printf prints the address of line... instead you coud use printf ("%d", atoi(line));

Answer (score 1):

To print a *string*, which `line` is, use `%s`:

```
printf("%s \n", line);
```

Now, if it really were an integer, you could use `%d`:

```
int num = atoi(line);
printf("%d \n", num );
```

What you're seeing is the result of treating a pointer type (which is what a string in C basically is) as an integer type.  Since pointers hold memory addresses, that -1079184140 is the actual address the pointer holds, represented as a 32 bit signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly the content of the file (three numbers separated by white space), why not directly read it?

```
if (fscanf(stream, "%d%d%d", &foo, &bar, &baz) < 3)
    // handle error

printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", foo, bar, baz);
```

But if you want to read lines, there are already other good answers.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file line by line for integers

```
  void read_file(char *filename, int *readbuff, int size)
   {
       FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
       if(fp == NULL){
          printf("Failed to open file %s \n", filename);
          return;
       }

       /*the condition in for loop checks if the integer was read into
        readbuff[i] and the readbuff is not overflown*/
       for(int i = 0 ; fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&readbuff[i]) == 1  && i < size; ++i);

       fclose(fp);
       return;
   }
```